# Creating a shared link for an item in a Sharepoint list returns BadRequest - resource not found

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Per documentation there's an option to create a sharing link for an item in a Sharepoint list - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/listitem-createlink?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http

Tested it with code and all I get are bad requests

endpoint = https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/mysharepointsite/lists/mytestlist/items/1/createLink

result:

```
{'error': {'code': 'BadRequest',
       'innerError': {'client-request-id': '64033979-ec68-493a-84e5-881c93870f5c',
                      'date': '2022-12-02T13:45:22',
                      'request-id': '64033979-ec68-493a-84e5-881c93870f5c'},
       'message': "Resource not found for the segment 'createLink'."}}
```

Is the API broken on this particular topic?

P.S. Removing the createLink option at the end returns the expected details of that specific item.

Answer (score 1):

`createLink` endpoint is currently available only for `Beta` version but you are calling `v1.0` version.

Use `beta` in URL

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/mysharepointsite/lists/mytestlist/items/1/createLink
```